# jQuery click fires on second click but not first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've checked some other threads but can't seem to find a response that goes with my code. My issue is my click event only fires on the second click, at which point it works perfectly (second click opens, third click closes, fourth opens, etc...)

```
$('.expand-btn').click(function() {
      var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
      if (clicks) {
        $('.expand-wrapper').animate({
            right: "0"
        }, 500, function() {

        });
      } else {
        $('.expand-wrapper').animate({
            right: "-325px"
        }, 500, function() {

        });
      }
      $(this).data('clicks', !clicks);
    });
```

EDIT: Here is my HTML code. It works like [this jquery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Feedback-Box-Plugin-with-jQuery-feedBackBox/) where `.expand-wrapper` is the contact form which is hidden off screen and `.expand-btn` is the little flap that is on the side of the screen and clickable.

```
<div class="expand-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="expand-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a>
    <div class="expand-form">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2173" title="Home 01 Request_no_title"]'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any initial value set for your `data-clicks` attribute? If not, you might want to consider setting one as it sounds like it isn't being set until the first time it is clicked with the `$(this).data('clicks')` attribute.

Comment: Okay you're right I think. When I click first it sets `right` to `-325px`. I'm a little list at this point; how/what/where would I set data-clicks?

Comment: Why you don't put onclick  attribute on a href and remove href just use simple anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue where your `data-clicks` attribute isn't initialized on your element (as you are setting it at the end of your first click and then it appears to work as expected).

Try initializing it on your `.expand-btn` element as follows :

```
<a href="#" class="expand-btn" data-clicks='false'>...</a>
```

Or if you have multiple expand button elements, you can initialize them when your page is loaded using jQuery :

```
$(function(){
     $('.expand-btn').data('clicks',false);
});
```

Comment: I added that but it didn't work. I updated my code and added my HTML. I might have done it differently than you imaged.

Comment: Apparently my original response was pointing to the wrong element (i.e. `expand-button` as opposed to `expand-btn`). I've also added an example using your recent code snippet, which should help.

Comment: Hmm so I've added but still nothing. I just figured out a temporary solution that if I change the values in my code (first block get `-325px`, second gets `0`) it works fine.